# Flutter: Navigate to specific tab on a different screen

Tags: flutter

On the home page of my app, I have a list of pictures which each need to be linked to a specific tab on a separate page. How can this be done in Flutter/Dart? Someone mentioned passing in parameters, but it seems like overkill.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use MaterialPageRoute to pass any data to another screen.

page1.dart

```
    onTap: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => DetailScreen(detail: 'myDetail parm'),
        ),
      );
```

page2.dart

```
class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String detail;

  DetailScreen({Key key, @required this.todo}) : super(key: key);
```

Take a look on Flutter docs : [Send data to a new screen](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/passing-data)

Answer (score 0):

```
 onPressed: () {
   Navigator.push(
         context,
     MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ScreenName()),
     );
 }
```